# Elixir: string to datetime

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Anyone have any luck with a `String` to `DateTime` kinda function in Elixir or Phoenix? The [documentation](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/DateTime.html) has nothing like a `parse/1` function.

Preferably from a string that looks like:

```
08/02/2016 6:15 PM
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's no such function in Elixir or Phoenix. Ecto has some basic datetime parsers but they cannot parse the example string you've posted. You can use a datetime library like [`timex`](https://github.com/bitwalker/timex) for this. Here's how you would parse the example string with timex:

```
iex(1)> Timex.parse("08/02/2016 6:15 PM", "{0D}/{0M}/{YYYY} {h12}:{m} {AM}")
{:ok, ~N[2016-02-08 18:15:00]}
```

(Swap `0D` and `0M` if you meant this date to parse to Aug 2 instead of Feb 8.)

Comment: Ah, thanks! That's way better than the horrible parser I was trying to write.